# Java Spring Derby - datasource specific to unit tests

Tags: java, spring, jpa, derby

So, I'm working on a Spring Rest API using JPA and based on an Oracle database.

I have some unit tests, mostly very specific (like regex checks). 
I also have some bigger integration tests and at the moment they would interact with the real database.

What I want is to use Derby for the tests and Oracle for the real app.

In an application.properties file, I have the properties for the two datasource scenarios.
I have no other configuration file, no XML file in the entire project

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:1521/orcl
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
#spring.datasource.username=user
#spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
spring.datasource.urljdbc:derby:target/database/message;create=true
spring.datasource.username=app
spring.datasource.password=app
```

also:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

by manually commenting, uncommenting the right block in the properties file, i can either use derby or the real oracle DB
I would like to make that process automatic by having two "named datasources" that i can use. I'm no Spring expert :-)

What's the easiest/recommended way to achieve this?

Please if you mention some XML, tell me where they should go or how they should be referenced as i don't know about them and there seems to be very conflicting advice online depending on wether you use Spring, EE, different versions of JPA, etc.

Many Thanks!

Comment: How did you specify the Derby dependency so that those jars are only used at test, and not packaged with the application?

Answer (score 3):

You can annotate your Tests with the annotation `@TestPropertySource` which:

> can be used to selectively override properties defined in system and
>   application property sources

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-spring

So, you can remove the test database properties from `application.properties` and either put them into a separate file and specify that as a value for `@TestPropertySource` or you can use the inline mechanism e.g.

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(
    locations = "/test.db.properties"
)
public class MyDatabaseTest{

}
```

or

```
   @ContextConfiguration
    @TestPropertySource(
        properties = {
            "spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver", 
            "spring.datasource.urljdbc:derby:target/database/message;create=true",
            "spring.datasource.username=app",
            "spring.datasource.password=app"
        }
    )
    public class MyDatabaseTest {

    }
```

Comment: As Alan pointed out, `@TestPropertySource` does the trick. I prefer inlining properties in the test source, so that the test is self contained

Comment: Thanks!  There is also the option of having a different application.properties file in /src/test/resource. It seems to be picked up automatically.      

Related question: Is it possible to have one integration test run with both the Derby DB and the Oracle DB by attaching a subset of tests to both configurations or even run the whole testSuite successively on both DB?

Comment: Yes, separate resources under src/test is an approach I have taken with xml config files. Maybe the above approach offers a bit more flexibility however. I think you should open a new question for any further issues.

Comment: I think an equals sign is missing in the spring.datasource.urljdbc:... line above, please fix.